# Make sense create a property for a BOOL instance var?

Tags: objective-c, properties, boolean

Make sense create a property for a BOOl instance var?

Is it only tied to notation?

Comment: Sense question your make not.

Comment: @occulus, Have you ever been so far even as decided to use go want to look more like?

Comment: I guess @Fran is not fluent in English. Don't expect everyone to speak a certain language. Could you answer him, if he asks his question in his native language? We should appreciate his effort to ask the question in english.

Comment: @Simon, I gave it a shot.  I was more making fun of @occulus, using a rather well-known meme.  I wasn't sure what @Fran meant by "tied to notation" but I gave it a shot.  Also, [@Fran's english isn't all that bad.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091584/the-nav-bar-doesnt-resize-properly-in-landscape-mode)

Comment: I'm not english mother tongue, sometimes I use a translator, but when I'm in hurry I don't. I realized that my question is not clear so I'm sorry for this. Maybe I'd have deleted it, but it's not possible with answers. I wondered if a property for a primitive type could have a sense as I didn't understand how it was possible "retain" it. And if it's accessed from another class, it always possible to create own getter/setter without any particular problem.

Comment: As concerns the "tied to notation", I thought that one reason for having a property for a BOOL was the possibility to use the dot notation, but I was wrong 'cause a member var is accessible by its name directly (myBool = NO works, self.myBool = NO doesn't, if myBool isn't a property). Ultimately, I deserve -2 for this not well-asked question.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani: what does it mean "Have you ever been so far even as decided to use go want to look more like?". I've not found a good translation neither for this or for the word "meme".

Comment: @Fran, I'm sorry, I hate making big deals out of other people's grammar.  A ["meme"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme) is an internet thing - usually stupid humor.  The statement I posted [can be explained here.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/has-anyone-really-been-far-as-decided-to-use-even-go-want-to-do-look-more-like)  Again, sorry, too much caffeine addled my brain.  :(

Comment: @Fran, the answer to your question about `retain` and writing your own getters/setters is **yes**.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani: Don't worry :) I learned one more thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BOOL`s can be properties like any other variable.  You should declare them as `assign`ed, however because `retain/copy` have little to no meaning for a `BOOL`.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myState;

@end


@implementation MyObject

@synthesize myState = _myState;

- (id) init
{
  if (( self = [super init])) {
    self.myState = NO;
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

One use of `@property` is, we can access the property from other classes. For instance, consider you are declaring the BOOL property like the following,

`@property (nonatomic) BOOL myState;`

Now you can access `myState` property from other class. Otherwise it is not possible to access the BOOL variable from other classes. If you are not going to access this BOOL variable from other classes, you may omit the `@property` declaration.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myState; Instead with retain/copy, it'll result in a compile error.

Comment: @Fran: Yeah sorry.. By mistake I added `retain` there.. I corrected it now.