# Auto Resizing UINavigationBar on rotation to landscape

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

The typical NavController behaviour is to resize when in port/landscape. From 44px height to 32px I beleive (from the top of my head).

I am using a storyboard and included a Navigation Bar into a VC, not controller. When rotating between portrait and landscape the navigation bar does not resize automatically.

I have seen this answer but this does not help : [Resizing UINavigationBar on rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826011/resizing-uinavigationbar-on-rotation)

The Navigation Bar is controller via appearance which is loaded in the App Delegate:

```
UIImage *portraitImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mainNavBar"];
UIImage *landscapeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mainNavBarLandscape"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:portraitImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:landscapeImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                       [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                       [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],
                                                       UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,nil]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
```

Unfortunately the last part makes no difference and as the navigation bar will be included in multiple controllers I do not want to repeat the same glue code in the question above's answer to all my VCs to resize on rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
```

But you didn't say flexible height. Yet height, as I understand it, is the very feature you wish to be flexible.

Comment: Correct, I also noticed that shortly after posting. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you are using autolayout, the `UINavigationBar`'s `intrinsicContentSize` updates correctly on rotation but its height `NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint` doesn't. Calling `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` manually tells autolayout to update the height constraint for the navigation bar.

```
// View controller
public override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
  super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator);

  self.navigationBar?.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer worked for me, but I wanted to move to full constraint based layout.

Setting the `UIBarPosition` on the `UINavBar` delegate positioned things as needed. Remember to attach the delegate in IB (of course).

```
// In my view controller

#pragma mark - UIBarPositioningDelegate
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

For constraints on the `UINavBar` in IB:

- Top Space to: Top Layout Guide (0)
- Leading Space to: Superview (0)
- Training Space to: Superview (0)
- most importantly.... no height constraint of any kind!  -

The height will be determined by content size at runtime. Originally I couldn't get this work properly because I had the Vertical Content Hugging Priority at 750, but that was wrong. When I changed it back to the default (250) it worked fine.

Comment: The above doesn't seem to ever adjust the size of the toolbar. I believe it is supposed to be 32 pt high in landscape on ≤4-inch devices. This technique seems to only take care of adjusting the toolbar position for the presence or absence of a status bar.